# How are exceptions handled by the browser?

Tags: html, ecmascript-6

I decided to figure out how the browser processes the script with only one line in the code, and this line is an exception.

Let's say we have this exception:

```
throw Error("custom error");
```

By specification ecma262 [ThrowStatement](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-throw-statement-runtime-semantics-evaluation) returns a completion record with throw type.
When the script [ScriptEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation) is executed:

> 12. If result.[[Type]] is normal, then
>
>     - Set result to the result of evaluating scriptBody.

---

> 17. Return Completion(result).

this makes it clear to us that a completion record with throw type is returned from [ScriptEvaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-runtime-semantics-scriptevaluation)

But the ecma262 specification does not say when an error is thrown to the console. I need help to see how whatwg specification intercepts error throw from ecma262.

Comment: I don't think this is standardized, but the steps for evaluating a script can be found here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#calling-scripts .

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for that link. Can you say me what means a *rethrow errors*?

Comment: @MaximPro The spec there says "an optional rethrow errors boolean:". It is a boolean argument to the function. `rethrow` meaning that the error will be passed further up the call stack as an error.

Comment: @loganfsmyth accordingly for my line there is no rethrow argument. And in what code can this argument arise?

Comment: "accordingly for my line there is no rethrow argument" I'm sorry, I don't know what that means. "And in what code can this argument arise?" Please take time to look over the linked spec. If you follow the links for usage of that function, one of them goes directly to https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/workers.html#importing-scripts-and-libraries:run-a-classic-script which states "Run the classic script script, with the rethrow errors argument set to true." so the answer is that `importScripts()` throws the error into whatever code called it. That might log it later, but could also catch.

Comment: @loganfsmyth I meant `throw Error ("custom error");` when I talked about "my line". And about the question: "what code can this argument arise?" - I meant the real javascript code that causes the logical argument rethrow which is given. Besides the moment with import (`importScripts()`), there are other cases when the logical argument rethrow is passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you're seeing is specified in the WHATWG HTML standard (emphasis mine).

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#calling-scripts

> 8. Otherwise, set evaluationStatus to ScriptEvaluation(script's record).
>      If ScriptEvaluation does not complete because the user agent has aborted the running script, leave evaluationStatus as null.
> 9. If evaluationStatus is an abrupt completion, then:
>
>    1. ...
>    2. ...
>    3. Otherwise, rethrow errors is false. Perform the following steps:
>
>       1. **Report the exception given by evaluationStatus.[[Value]] for script.**
>       2. Clean up after running script with settings.
>       3. Return evaluationStatus.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#runtime-script-errors-in-documents

> When the user agent is to report an exception E, the user agent must report the error for the relevant script, with the problematic position (line number and column number) in the resource containing the script, using the global object specified by the script's settings object as the target. If the error is still not handled after this, then **the error may be reported to a developer console.**

Also, ECMAScript doesn't actually have a console, that's specified at https://console.spec.whatwg.org